# NameError: name 'width' is not defined

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, imagefilter

I am trying to implement a median filter in python using the following code

```
    from PIL import Image
    path = "gaussian.png" # Your image path 
    img = Image.open(path)
    width, height = Image.size
    members = [(0,0)] * 9
    newimg = Image.new("RGB",(width,height),"white")
    for i in range(1,width-1):
       for j in range(1,height-1):
             members[0] = img.getpixel((i-1,j-1))
             members[1] = img.getpixel((i-1,j))
             members[2] = img.getpixel((i-1,j+1))
             members[3] = img.getpixel((i,j-1))
             members[4] = img.getpixel((i,j))
             members[5] = img.getpixel((i,j+1))
             members[6] = img.getpixel((i+1,j-1))
             members[7] = img.getpixel((i+1,j))
             members[8] = img.getpixel((i+1,j+1))
             members.sort()
             newimg.putpixel((i,j),(members[4]))
```

however I keep getting an error saying NameError: name 'width' is not defined

Comment: You need to set the value of width and height in 'newimg = Image.new("RGB",(width,height),"white")'

Comment: because it's not defined... neither height.

Comment: did it never cross your mind that you maybe should check if you're using an undefined variable called 'width'? I'm sure there was also a line number given with that error message... come on!

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You're trying to use variables that don't exist. How should Python know what value `width` and `height` are supposed to take?

Comment: @Rakesh
I've tried to set it by 
   Width = 100
    Height = 100
But it says invalid syntax and I don't know how else you would set it

Comment: @RK1. Can you update your code in the que?

Comment: @Rakesh Just updated it

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the image size of the image you are reading.

replace

```
width, height = Image.size
```

**with**

```
width, height = img.size
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept ans if it solved your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Neither height or width is defined.

You could maybe get the height and width of your image by doing the following:

```
width, height = img.size
```

I hope this is useful

Comment: I've tried this just now and IDLE is saying that PIL image has no attribute 'size'

Comment: my bad, refer to the answer by Rakesh - it should be img.size

Answer (score 0):

Please find working code here. might help
    from PIL import Image

```
def main():
    path = "gaussian.png" # Your image path 
    img = Image.open(path)
    width, height = img.size
    print(width, height)
    members = [(0,0)] * 9
    newimg = Image.new("RGB",(width,height),"white")
    for i in range(1,width-1):
        for j in range(1,height-1):
            members[0] = img.getpixel((i-1,j-1))
            members[1] = img.getpixel((i-1,j))
            members[2] = img.getpixel((i-1,j+1))
            members[3] = img.getpixel((i,j-1))
            members[4] = img.getpixel((i,j))
            members[5] = img.getpixel((i,j+1))
            members[6] = img.getpixel((i+1,j-1))
            members[7] = img.getpixel((i+1,j))
            members[8] = img.getpixel((i+1,j+1))
            members.sort()
            newimg.putpixel((i,j),(members[4]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```